# Why is my car dying and my temp gauge reading hot?

Tags: overheating

2005 Trailblazer LS

I noticed my coolant in my reservoir was low so I added more. Now when I slow down sometimes it dies. It never smokes and I don't smell antifreeze but the gauge is saying hot.  The engine isn't significantly hot either.

Could this be a sign of a failing head?

Please, I am dumbfounded, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually overheating? What is the temperature of the coolant? The oil? The intake air temperature? Coolant temperature gauges in non-racing automobiles are notoriously inaccurate. In most cars I have experience with, a "hot" reading means the coolant is dangerously high.

Comment: Well it's definitely not overheating,  and the only thing really happening other than the gauge going all the way to the right is that occasionally when I go to slow down,  it will die. It always starts right back up though. It maybe worth noting that the temp didn't work before I replaced the battery, but seemed to work once afterwards for a few hours, then suddenly it would say it's hot although there were no signs of overheating.  So idk, now it seems to be stuck all the way a good 2 inches past the hot mark and almost upside down.

Comment: Setting aside the gauge issue, can you get one of those OBD2 things and plug it in to read the car data? That should give you exact figures for how hot everything is. Heat can cause stalling around idle if the intake manifold's heat thins out the intake charge too much. You end up running too rich and the engine floods. But that's an issue I usually only see if an engine gets hot and then sits for ages. Usually the air doesn't sit in the manifold for long enough to cause problems. It could also be a faulty sensor of some sort. Or something completely different. Get a scanner.